# how to get thumbnail image from firebase after upload in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I am uploading video & images to firebase in swift. Now when upload is complete then I am getting the image url. But the url is of orignal image. I want when image or video is uploaded the I should get a thumnbnail image for image or video. I am using below code.

```
let imagePath = withName

        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = mimeType
        metadata.customMetadata = ["index": String(describing: index), "contentType": mimeType]

        // Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
        let uploadTask = storageRef.child(imagePath).put(data, metadata: metadata)

        // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
        uploadTask.observe(.resume) { snapshot in
            // Upload resumed, also fires when the upload starts
        }

        uploadTask.observe(.pause) { snapshot in
            // Upload paused
        }

        uploadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
            // Upload reported progress
            let percentComplete =  Double((snapshot.progress?.completedUnitCount)!)/Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)
            progress( String(format: "%.2f", percentComplete))
            print(percentComplete)
        }

        uploadTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in
            // Upload completed successfully
            //Download the the image from url and save it as Data in local directory
            print(snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString ?? "no url found......")
            completion(.success, (snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString), DIError.noResponse)

            // self.startDownloading(downloadUrl: (snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString)!, imageName: imagePath)
        }
```

Comment: FIRStorage is simply used to store the data. It won't automatically create a thumbnail. You need to use Firebase Function and add code for generating thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

We have an example of how to use Cloud Functions with Cloud Storage to generate thumbnails: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail

Thumbnails get saved back to Cloud Storage, and you can then download the appropriately sized photo.

Comment: That works only  for Image. What should I use for getting thumbnails of  video files?